# Access JSON data inside brackets - home({"a": { "prop1": "data", "prop2": "data"});

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I'm getting some result when calling to some service as below.

**Call:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function getData() {    

        var clientID = '123';
        var pageName = 'home';
        var serviceURL = 'https://service.com/meta?_callback=home&_o=' + clientID + '&_t=' + pageName + '';     

        $.ajax({
            url: serviceURL,
            method: 'GET',
            aynch:true,
            success: function (data) {   
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Service Call Error '+ errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Response:**

```
home({
      "a": {
       "prop1": "data",
        "prop2": "data"
      },
      "b": {
        "prop1": "data",
        "prop2": "data"
      }
});
```

How to access data of this result using JavaScript ?

Comment: What is the result of your service? This is just the call.

Comment: `home` function is defined?

Comment: reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks a lot like a JSONP response!

Have a read on what is JSONP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

```
<!-- call api -->
<script src="http://api.url.com?callback=home"></script>
<script>
     // handle response
     function home(data) {
         console.log(data);
     }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Thank you for all your valuable answers. It happened to be a JSONP response.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="'https://service.com/meta?_callback=home"></script>

<script>
    function home(data){
        console.log(data);
    }

    function getData() {    

        var clientID = '123';
        var pageName = 'home';
        var serviceURL = 'https://service.com/meta?_callback=home&_o=' + clientID + '&_t=' + pageName + '';     

        $.ajax({
            url: serviceURL,
            method: 'GET',
            jsonpCallback: 'home',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            aynch:true,
            success: function (data) { 
            },
            error: function (data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Service Call Error '+ errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

References :

https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

http://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/

Answer (score 0):

if it is a JSONP you have to define `home` function, for example:

```
var result;

window.home = function(data) {
  result = data;
}
```

then you can get props

```
result.a.prop1 // "data"
```